# Get a Value from One Cell in Sqlite to Livecode

Tags: sqlite, return-value, livecode

I am using sqlite as my database. It is connected to the livecode project.

The Contacts table has the following data (address and contact number are omitted for security)

```
ID            Name               Address            Contact No.
1             John               ...Philippines     0999999999
2             Kim                ...Philippines     0999999999
```

When I executed this command...

```
SELECT Name from Contacts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

It will return

```
Kim
```

In Livecode, I want to store that value to the variable and display it as a Message Box.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of LiveCodes database functions. First you need to open the database via:

```
revOpenDatabase("sqlite",filepath[,sqliteOptions])
```

Then you can query the database via one of the query commands:

```
revQueryDatabase(databaseID,SQLQuery[,{variablesList | arrayName}])
```

There is also a function called `revDataFromQuery([columnDelim],[rowDelim],databaseID,SQLQuery[,varsList])` that you might use for your query.

Look them up in your dictionary and you may also have a look at the "Book Database" provided via the start center.

So using the last function you can use:

```
put revOpenDatabase("sqlite","/path/to/your/database") into tDB
revDataFromQuery(,,tDB,"SELECT Name from Contacts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1", tResult)
answer tResult
```

(Using empty row and column delimiter as you only select one field in one post.)

Comment: Sorry the variable name in the revDataFromQuery should be just the name and must thus be enclosed in quotes so the tResult should be "tResult".

Comment: revDataFromQuery is actually a function, so a better syntax would be: put revDataFromQuery(,,tDB,tQuery) into tResult